# Cannot see mesh file in Gazebo 1.2.5

Tags: gazebo, mesh, gazebo-1.2, collada

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

The simulation does not visualize the mesh of a robotic hand model in Gazebo 1.2.5, which under Gazebo 1.0.2 worked fine.

The URI to the **.dae** file is correct in the sdf (v1.2) file. (I tried it with another **.dae** file from PR2 and it visualized it).

The difference between the files was that mine had **COLLADA** version **1.4.0**, and PR2 had version **1.4.1**. So I imported it in **Blender** and exported it as version **1.4.1** and it still did not work.

Here is [my original .dae](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-_Uvr2wQxS3ZmNDTTdwWDVpMEU) file, here it is [after converting it in 1.4.1](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-_Uvr2wQxS3S3IwdFBGMmJ3SkE) and this is a [PR2 .dae file](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-_Uvr2wQxS3YUtrc0x6X19rWnc) which works.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/491/cannot-see-mesh-file-in-gazebo-1.2.5/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like the collada file has incorrect units. Open up your original dae file, and go to this line:

`<unit meter="0.01" .../>`

Change to `meter="1.0"'

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2012-12-13**:
It worked, thanks a lot.